# Linq groupby return unique group

Tags: c#, linq, list, group-by

I have list of records, each record has **Name** and **Rounds**.
**Rounds** is a concatenated numbers seperated by **"-"**

[image]

How can i group by name and display only unique rounds, also count the number of rounds and display the first round and last round

[image]

Here is what i tried,

```
 data.GroupBy(d => d.Name)
.Select(
    g => new
    {
        Name = g.Key,
        Rounds = g.Concat(s => s.Rounds),
        NumberOfRounds =  g.Concat(s => s.Rounds).Split('-').Count,
        FirstRound = //??,
        LastRound = //??,
    });
```

Comment: Use `.SelectMany()` I am not at my computer or I would post an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would *start* by projecting your entity to a name and collection-of-rounds pair. That will then be easier to work with. For example:

```
var query = results
    .Select(d => new { d.Name, Results = d.Rounds.Split('-').Select(int.Parse).ToList() })
    .GroupBy(
        d => d.Name, (key, values) => new {
            Name = key,
            Rounds = values.SelectMany(v => v.Rounds)
                           .Distinct()
                           .OrderBy(x => x)
                           .ToList()
       });
```

With the rounds available as a list, I don't see that there's much point in having `NumberOfRounds`, `FirstRound` and `LastRound` as properties, as you can just use `Rounds.Count`, `Rounds.First()`, `Rounds.Last()`. The important part is transforming the data into a more useful format as early as possible.

If you really need that in properties, it's easy enough to project:

```
// query as before, but with
.Select(x => new {
    x.Name,
    x.Rounds,
    NumberOfRounds = x.Rounds.Count,
    FirstRound = x.Rounds.First(),
    LastRound = x.Rounds.Last()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to extract the rounds to numeric values. After that, it is easy.

```
var data = ...;
var groupedData = data
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(x => new {
        Name = x.Key,
        Rounds = string.Join("-", x.Select(z => z.Rounds))
            .Split('-')
            .Distinct()
            .Select(z => int.Parse(z))
            .OrderBy(z => z)
            .ToArray()
    })
    .Select(x => new {
        x.Name,
        Rounds = string.Join("-", x.Rounds),
        NumberOfRounds = x.Length,
        FirstRound = x.Min(),
        LastRound = x.Max()
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: @juharr Where are the parenthese off? And the `.ToArray()` is not part of the `string.Join(...)` call.

Comment: The `x` in the first `Select` is an `IGrouping` so it doesn't have a `Rounds` property.

Comment: @Maarten, Thx for answering my question!